# How to protect from wannacry on home wifi network

Tags: wifi, wannacry, windows-7

I am running an outdated Windows 7 and am not able to update it due to some reasons. I wanted to know how vulnerable is my Windows to WannaCry from the home wifi network connection. What would you recommend as an alternative solution to keep my Windows protected from it?

Comment: @nd510 I already have a paid AV - Bitdefender, but the thing is I am not sure whether I should connect to the internet for updating the virus definitions

Comment: @messi It's not like wannacry is waiting _there_ looking for vulnerable machines and infecting them the second they come online. It mostly spreads via emails. Just go online, update AV and you should be OK if you don't fall for some social engineering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WannaCry  spreads using windows SMB. One should be able to disable this completely. However i recommend you to update your system. You wont win the *hacking race* against thousands of people alone...

Checklist:

1. Block external access to the smb port at the router (139, 445).
2. Disable smb if not necessary

https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows-server

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2016/09/16/stop-using-smb1/

3. The usual anti- spam stuff
4. the usual mail/browser hardening

Comment: [email is not the primary infection vector](http://blog.talosintelligence.com/2017/05/wannacry.html)

Comment: @SYS_V thanks for this ressource + edited to make it more clear...

Comment: "WannaCry infected the first devices through emails" - please support this claim with evidence

Comment: @SYS_V looks like this was a missinformation i had because it was published right after the big incident by many researchers. However it looks like no one of them can actually proove it. Im sorry for that...

Comment: @SYS_V at least symantec does not know the first infection vector: https://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/what-you-need-know-about-wannacry-ransomware

Answer (score -1):

Fix the 'some reasons'.

That is the simplest option...  Unless the 'some reasons' are the use of a pirate version of the operating system, you should be able to get help with the issues that are preventing you from patching on SuperUser.

Comment: The reason is complications due to Dual Booting - I won't go into detail but it has rendered me helpless as of now, to install the patch or any other update. That's why I was looking for an alternative. Moreover, aren't systems connected to a home wifi safe until one is exposed to the malware via a suspicious attachment?

Comment: The answer remains the same though.  Fix the problem that  prevents you from patching.

Comment: That requires formatting the computer. *Sigh*

Comment: So you *can* fix the problem, WannaCry is one of a huge number of potential threats which can be mitigated by patching...  "I can't be bothered to maintain my system" seems like a poor reason for a downvote IMHO.

Comment: I didn't downvote it though. My situation demands me to use my computer but I can't due to the messed up boot. I was going to format anyway but wanted to delay it for the time being to finish my pending work.

Comment: I am curious what sort of issue with dual booting can prevent updating Windows. I've had a few dual-boot systems (and use one still) and never had problems applying Windows security updates...if I'd have read of widespread issues with that before starting I wouldn't have started in the first place.